# Let $X = S^2 \cap \{ z \geq 0 \}$, what is the border of X with respect to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $S^2?$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I'm trying to find the border of  $X = S^2 \cap \{ z \geq 0 \}$, where $S^2 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | \sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)} = 1 \}$ with the induced euclidean topology. I need to find the border with respect to the space $\mathbb{R}^3$ and with the space $S^2$.

This is what I have done so far. The border of X with respect to $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be written as: $$ Border(X) = Closure(X) \cap Closure(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus X)$$
I think this equals X itself, but I'm not too sure about that.

Similarly, the border of X with respect to $S^2$ can be written as:
$$ Border(X) = Closure(X) \cap Closure(S^2 \setminus X)$$

But now I'm not sure on how to proceed. Any hints?

Comment: You recieved an answers to your question. Is it what you were looking for? If so, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the boundary of $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$; it is indeed $X$ itself.

In $S^2$, $\overline X=X$, since $X$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and therefore a closed subset of $S^2$. On the other hand,$$S^2\setminus X=\{(x,y,z)\in S^2\,|\,z<0\}$$and so $\overline{S^2\setminus X}=S^2\cap\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,|\,z\leqslant0\}$. Therefore, the boundary of $X$ is the equator:$$\{(x,y,0)\,|\,x^2+y^2=1\}.$$

Comment: Thank you! Could you expand a bit on the first part of the question? My intuition tells me the result, but I'm struggling to prove it!

Comment: @LudovicoBessi I've edited my answer. I hope that it is clear now.